# ssh-agent forwarding through vscode Remote Tunnels

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I have setup [Remote Tunnels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels) into a remote server that does not allow SSH inbound connections. It's working great.

The only issue I have with this setup is that my local SSH keys are not forwarded to the remote server, so I cannot access other servers. Is there a way to achieve something equivalent to ssh-agent forwarding through the Remote Tunnels? I don't want to store private keys on the remote permanently.